# Need for ExecutorService.awaitTermination() after shutdown()

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

As per Javadocs, [shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) will wait for all submit tasks to be executed. I have two questions:

- What does submitted task mean? Do the tasks have to be submitted specifically by ExecutorService.submit() method or it included tasks submitted by ExecutorService.execute() method also?
- I have added a shutdown hook which calls ExecutorService.shutdown(). As per the docs, it should wait for all submit tasks to be executed. But it doesn't until I add a awaitTermination() call after the shutdown() call. Why doesn't it execute all tasks without awaitTermination() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does submitted task mean? Do the tasks have to be submitted specifically by ExecutorService.submit() method or it included tasks submitted by ExecutorService.execute() method also?

A 'submitted' task in this sense is any Runnable or Callable that was passed to the ExecutorService. Although the wording of the javadoc is slightly confusing, it does not differentiate between `execute()` vs `submit()`.

> I have added a shutdown hook which calls ExecutorService.shutdown(). As per the docs, it should wait for all submit tasks to be executed. But it doesn't until I add a awaitTermination() call after the shutdown() call. Why doesn't it execute all tasks without awaitTermination() call?

The shutdown() operation is non-blocking (asynchronous) as are almost all of the methods on the ExecutorService API. The javadoc only states that calling `shutdown()` will *initiate* a shutdown sequence.

The key here is that the ExecutorService will **try** to wait for all tasks to complete, but if `shutdown()` is the last line of code before your main method terminates, `System.exit()` will be called after the end of your main method which will terminate the JVM and override the ExecutorService's attempt to wait for running tasks to complete. I would consider it undesireable for `ExecutorService.shutdown()` to always delay a `System.exit()`, and would prefer an opt-in approach to a blocking call (i.e. `awaitTermination`).

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745621/executor-shutdown-still-waits-for-tasks-to-complete-with-no-invokeall-or-await